# Symfony2 + FOSUserBundle: 2 login forms

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, fosuserbundle

I am having trouble getting a login page to work on the www subdomain. The security for the login is as follows:

```
firewalls:
main:
    pattern: ^/
    host: my.mydomain.dev
    form_login:
        check_path: '/login_check'
        login_path: '/login'
        default_target_path: '/'
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
    logout:
        path: '/logout'
        target: '/login'
    anonymous: true
    switch_user: true
access_control:
    # ASSETS NEEDED ON ALL PAGES #
    - { path: ^/assets/img, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/assets/css, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/assets/js, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    # END ASSETS NEEDED ON ALL PAGES #

    - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/, roles: ROLE_USER, host: my.domain.dev }
    - { path: ^/, host: linkmetrix.dev, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

I have a login page at `www.mydomain.com/login` and a login page at `my.mydomain.com/login`.

When I login to the page at `my.mydomain.com/login` it works perfectly.  Trying to figure out how to get a login page at `www.mydomain.com/login` to coincide with that, where the end result will take me to `my.mydomain.com`

Thanks for any help!

I have tried to create a second `firewall` for the front end, but nothing I have done seems to work.  Any advice, techniques or tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue and found out that I needed to adjust the domain that is set in the session cookie when the user is logged in.  The reason being that the sub domain is set to where the user logged in so eliminating the sub-domain portion from the session fixed the issue.

Go to the config.yml file and add this line:

```
framework:
   session:
       cookie_domain: "domain.com"
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony should not care which domain you are using for the firewall, try removing the `host: my.mydomain.dev` directive.

Answer (score 0):

Every domain/subdomain needs to have the firewall properly configured with the relative `access_control`.

Then you need to add to your `access_control`:

Wrong:

`- { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

Correct:

`- { host: my.domain.dev, path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
- { host: my.domain.dev, path: ^/login_check, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }`

So for any domain you need to add the `host:` param on `access_control`.

I don't know your use case and why you need that but you can specify the target path in any firewall you want with

`form_login:
    always_use_default_target_path: true
    default_target_path: your_target_path`

**EDIT:** But user, after the redirect, will probably have some authentication problem **because multiple firewalls don't share security context**.
An alternative to resolve the problem is to add the same `context` directive as [described in the DOCS](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#reference-security-firewall-context)

Comment: That makes sense, so a firewall for `my.domain.dev` and `www.domain.dev` and the `access_control` to match.  With this, how would I get it to automatically redirect from `www.domain.dev/login` to `my.domain.dev` upon successful login?